# How to find the start_time and end_time range if found in the range then check start_date and end_date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have a below table in the database.

```
    id | list_id |venue_id |name | start_date | end_date   |start_time | end_time 
    1  |       1 |  1      |asdf |  2019-02-02| 2019-02-28 |05:30      |10:00
    2  |       7 |  2      |awed |  2019-02-10| 2019-02-20 |07:30      |14:00
    3  |       7 |  1      |mjgd |  2019-02-04| 2019-02-13 |09:30      |18:00
```

Now, I have to find the start_date and end_date of `venue_id=1` between the range of `2019-02-04` and `2019-03-01`. So I used below query.

```
SELECT * FROM `batch_list` WHERE `venue_id` = 1 and ((start_date between '2019-02-04' and '2019-03-01') OR (end_date between '2019-02-04' and '2019-03-01'))
```

Now I have to find the date and time of the venue_id=1 which is a range of `2019-02-04` and `2019-03-01` and `05:00` to `18:00`. So I tried below query

```
SELECT * FROM `batch_list` WHERE `venue_id` = 1 and ((start_date between '2019-02-04' and '2019-03-01') OR (end_date between '2019-02-04' and '2019-03-01')) and((start_time <= `end_time`) and (`start_time` between '05:00' and '18:00')and (end_time between '05:00' and '18:00'))
```

So there is no issue till now.

I have a time which is `05:00` to `20:00` then I am getting the all the records with related to the venue_id 1 but If I change the time `10:00` to `13:00` then I am not getting the records.

I need to find out the is there any start_time and end_time is available in the range or not. If found then check the start_date and end_date.

Would you help me out in this issue?

Model

```
function fetchBatches($venue_id,$new_batch_start_date,$new_batch_end_date,$new_batch_start_time,$new_batch_end_time)
    {
$where="batch_venue_id='$venue_id' and ((start_date between '$new_batch_start_date' and '$new_batch_end_date')OR (end_date between '$new_batch_start_date' and '$new_batch_end_date')) and ((start_time<=end_time) and (start_time < '$new_batch_start_time' and start_time < '$new_batch_end_time'))";

        $result =$this->db->select('*')    
                    ->from('batch_list')
                    ->where($where)
                    ->get()
                    ->result();
            if ($result) {
                 return $result;
            }
            else{
                 return 0;
            }

    }
```

Comment: 10:00 to 01:00 = `between 10 and 24 or 0 and 1` ?

Comment: Oh! I miss that. Wait, I am updating the question. That is 10:00 to 13:00. Updated question.

Comment: You could save yourself a world of pain by storing date and time as a single entity

Comment: I don't understand - do you really want to find overlap of two time interval?

Comment: @splash58, I have a records already in the table. If admin want to create venue_id =1 records again then first it will check the start_time and end_time are available or not in the records if records are available then it will check the dates

Comment: @splash58, My main aim is, admin can't create any records if the found any range of the time and dates. for example: venue_id=1 is booked for the date from 2019-02-02 to 2019-02-28 and time is 05:30  to 10:30. If admin try to create any records on same id then it will check the time and date

Comment: Yes, you want check that your time interval don't overlap any one in db.There are many such questions on SO

Comment: Don't separate date and time - you question should be - venue_id=1 is booked for the date from `2019-02-02 05:30` to `2019-02-28 10:30`

Comment: @splash58, Yes, I checked on SO, but that is only chekcking the time. My senario is if found time then also check the date as well

Comment: @splash58, I have a field where admin can enter the start_time and end_time.

Comment: Unfortunately, you save not DateTime field, and you will be need to make it by mysql functions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187759/discussion-between-user9437856-and-splash58).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some people suggested, it's better to combine date and time into the database.

For your question, I think that the query you want is this one:

```
SELECT * FROM batch_list 
WHERE    venue_id = 1
         AND (start_date <= '2019-03-01') 
         AND (start_time <= '13:00:00')
         AND (end_date >= '2019-02-04')
         AND (end_time >= '10:00:00')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Give me some time to check

Comment: Updated my answer, try again and tell me if it still doesn't work

Comment: Let me try again.

Comment: 2019-03-01 is the end date and 13:00:00 is end time... correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, it checks if there is any booking between 2019-02-04 10:00 and 2019-01-03 13:00

Comment: I have a little bit of concern, incase venue_id is multiple then how can I check it? I mean for example, venue_id = 1,2

Comment: It wouldn't be a problem, you can add another condition for venue, like ```WHERE (venue_id = 1 OR venue_id = 2) AND ...```

Comment: before few days I change the table and venue id, I mean now I am getting the venue id in the column like 1,3,4.... I am getting the error unknown column '1,3,4' in 'where clause'. should I use to explode function for this?

Comment: I don't understand. Did you change the table structure and venue_id stores more than one id ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187942/discussion-between-dialex-and-user9437856).

Comment: I am getting the same issue. I am using your answer but this time I have to check the days. Can you help me out in this issue   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54721274/how-to-check-the-id-is-booked-of-for-specific-days

Comment: I am straggling to find this issue from from last 8-9 days..Please help me out in this issue..please please