# How to check the id is booked of for specific days?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have a table and records are like below table.

```
id | list_id |venue_id |name | start_date          | end_date           |start_time |end_time | days 
1  |       1 |  1      |asdf |  2019-02-02 14:05:54| 2019-02-28 14:05:54|05:30      |10:00    | 1,2,3
2  |       7 |  2      |awed |  2019-02-10 15:02:24| 2019-02-20 15:02:24|07:30      |14:00    | 2,5
3  |       7 |  1      |mjgd |  2019-02-04 09:05:54| 2019-02-13 09:05:54|09:30      |18:00    | 4
```

Now What I am doing is I have to check the start_time and end_time range if found in the range then check start_date and end_date are in the range if found then display the records.

So below query is working for the above scenario

```
SELECT * FROM batch_list 
WHERE venue_id=1 AND (start_date <= '2019-03-01') AND (start_time <= '13:00:00') AND (end_date >= '2019-02-04') AND (end_time >= '10:00:00')";
```

Now I have one more column which is `days`. So what I am doing is `venue_id=1` is booked for a day which is 1,2,3,4 then display the records.

So how do i check the days which is already booked for id 1?

So what query I have to the user it to check the days are already in the table or not of the venue id=1?

```
function fetchBatches($venue_id,$new_batch_start_date,$new_batch_end_date,$new_batch_start_time,$new_batch_end_time,$days)
    {
$where="venue_id=$venue_id AND (start_date <= '$new_batch_end_date') AND (start_time <= '$new_batch_end_time') AND (end_date >= '$new_batch_start_date') AND (end_time >= '$new_batch_start_time')";

        $result =$this->db->select('*')    
                    ->from('batch_list')
                    ->where($where)
                    ->get()
                    ->result();
            if ($result) {
                 return $result;
            }
            else{
                 return 0;
            }

    }
```

Would you help me out on this issue?

Comment: Step 1. Store date and time as a single entity. Then get back to us.

Comment: @Strawberry, Wait I am editing the table.

Comment: Good. Once done , please add the desired result.

Comment: Ok, now your time columns make no sense. Can you simply remove them?

Comment: @Strawberry, I added the time in the table. Now it will good for me. if you share the example for better understand what type of time you need in the table.

Comment: @Strawberry, why remove? for example. I have to create a session which is from tomorrow so the date is 2019-02-17 but I need a time to start the session around 14:00 to 18:00 then how to set the time?

Comment: ? `2019-02-17 14:00:00`, `2019-02-17 18:00:00`

Comment: @Strawberry, So how can I set time in the date picker to catch the custom time?

Comment: @Strawberry, please check this link It is the UI . https://prnt.sc/mltxh3

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand

Comment: `1,2,3` in days show that your table is not in 1 NF.

Comment: I need to know how can I set the date with time something like start date 2019-02-17 14:00:00 and end date 2019-02-17 18:00:00?

Comment: @vivek_23, Yes, I am agreed with you. So you mean to say I have to insert total 4 records for the venue id 1 with different days. correct?

Comment: What's the problem- the user inputs a start date and a start time. The application code then squishes these together prior to submitting to the database (although personally I think this is a clumsy UI - after all, there are thousands of datetime pickers out there)

Comment: Yes, about the days bit... I was just getting to that.,,

Comment: @Strawberry, I found one plugin which is https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/. I can set date and time both.. but if I have to find the range like to check the date and time then how can I do that? Like I have a date start date 2019-02-17 14:00:00 and end date 2019-03-18 18:00:00 then I have to check the date and time both.. because I have to display the records which is in the range of the date and time.

Comment: @user9437856 Yes correct.

Answer (score 0):

A query to check whether one range overlaps another might look like this:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
 WHERE x.start_datetime < :end_datetime
   AND x.end\datetime >= :start_datetime;
```

But really your question is broader than this